# We need a canonical "She needs cash for passport/visa/airfare/permit/whatever to visit me" question

Tags: discussion

We need a generic question to cover all cases of romance scam:

- [Visitor requesting a cash advance to purchase airfare in-country. Legitimate or scam?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/104192/visitor-requesting-a-cash-advance-to-purchase-airfare-in-country-legitimate-or)
- [A Russian girl is asking for 500 euros to get a passport in Russia. Is this a realistic amount of money for a passport fee?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62633/a-russian-girl-is-asking-for-500-euros-to-get-a-passport-in-russia-is-this-a-re)
- [Is this request for proof of funds for Russian citizen legitimate?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100151/is-this-request-for-proof-of-funds-for-russian-citizen-legitimate)
- [Large cash requirement (2700 USD) for Russian citizens to fly to the US?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/94217/large-cash-requirement-2700-usd-for-russian-citizens-to-fly-to-the-us)
- [Does a Ghana citizen need $3000 in hand to travel to the USA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/84952/does-a-ghana-citizen-need-3000-in-hand-to-travel-to-the-usa)
- [Does a verified US citizen need a police & medical report to return from Ghana?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/90153/does-a-verified-us-citizen-need-a-police-medical-report-to-return-from-ghana)

And probably others.

Then we can close any new ones that come up as a duplicate.

Comment: What would the canonical answer be? "It's a scam"?

Comment: @JoErNanO Essentially, yes.  Isn't it always?

Comment: I don't know that's why I am asking. :)

Comment: "If you have to ask, it's probably a scam" should be the top answer.

Comment: General formula: woman+online+money = scam

Comment: Make that "someone claiming to be a woman"  ;-)

Comment: @user13267 not always — my Russian teacher on italki is online but is not a scam (and certainly not asking for €500)

Answer (score 7):

Your wish is my command :-) Here's the canonical:

[My online friend is asking for my money in order to visit my home country. Is this a legit request or a scam?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/104281/my-online-friend-is-asking-for-my-money-in-order-to-visit-my-home-country-is-th)

Let's create a good canonical answer now.

Comment: "Someone says they need money to be able to travel." is even more generic.  Too broad?

Comment: @WGroleau even better.